# How to run docker with bind mount in windows?

Tags: windows, docker, mount

Please, observe:

```
C:\work\azure-voting-app-redis [master ≡ +1 ~1 -0 !]> docker run -it tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6 --mount 'type=bind,source=c:\work\azure-voting-app-redis\azure-vote\ca-certs,target=/ca-certs' bash
/entrypoint.sh: 46: exec: --mount: not found
C:\work\azure-voting-app-redis [master ≡ +1 ~1 -0 !]>
```

All I am trying to do is run bash from the given image while mounting a local directory into the container. The error is not very helpful.

I am running it on Windows in a powershell console.

What am I doing wrong (besides running it on Windows) ?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. My command line was incorrect. I should have mentioned `--mount` before `-it`, like this:

```
docker run  --mount 'type=bind,source=c:\work\azure-voting-app-redis\azure-vote\ca-certs,target=/ca-certs' -it tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6 bash
```